Every bounded measurable function is the pointwise almost everywhere limit of continuous functions
Problem:
For every bounded measurable function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, there exists a sequence of continuous functions $f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ that converges pointwise almost everywhere to $f$.
Proof (attempt):
Let $h_n$ be any sequence of bounded simple functions converging pointwise to $f$ on $[0,1]$ and let $\epsilon>0$. By Lusin's theorem, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a continuous function $g_n:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and a closed subset $F_n\subset [0,1]$ such that

$g_n = h_n$ on $F_n$,
$\mu([0,1]\setminus F_n) < \epsilon/2^{n}$

Let $F = \cap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} F_n$. Then clearly $F\subset [0,1]$ and $F\subset F_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Further, by DeMorgan's law and countable subadditivity of measures,
$$\mu([0,1]\setminus F) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu([0,1]\setminus F_n ) < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2^n} = \epsilon.$$
Thus $\mu([0,1]\setminus F)<\epsilon$ and since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary it follows that $[0,1]\setminus F$ has measure zero. Further, if $x\in F$ then $x\in F_n$ for all $n$, so $g_n(x)=h_n(x)\to f(x)$ since $h_n\to f$ pointwise on $[0,1]$. Thus $g_n\to f$ pointwise on $F$. Let $f_n$ be the restriction of $g_n$ to $[0,1]$. It follows that $f_n$ is continuous as the restriction of continuous functions $g_n$ and converges pointwise almost everywhere on $[0,1]$ since it converges pointwise on $F$ and $F$ has measure zero. QED.
Question:
I think my attempted has flaws. Firstly, I am fairly confident that in the application of Lusin's theorem the choice of the continuous function $g_n$ and the closed set $F_n$ depend on $\epsilon>0$, hence I don't think we can say $\mu([0,1]\setminus F)<\epsilon$ holds for all $\epsilon>0$ since changing $\epsilon$ requires changing $F =\cap_n F_n$, no?
Secondly, even if this wasn't a problem, the rest of the arguments feels a little sloppy to me but I am not sure how to tighten it up.
Can anyone confirm/deny my doubts and/or push me into the right direction, or better direction if there are other ways of proving this. I would prefer hints over full solutions. Thanks in advanced.

Proof using some standard theorems: Your function $f$ is integrable, so there is a sequence of continuous functions $(f_n)$ converging to $f$ in $L^{1}$. This implies that there is a subsequence of $(f_n)$ converging a.e. to $f$ [Lusin's Theoerm is hidden here !].

@geetha290krm I don't quite see the hidden Lusin's theorem at first glance, but I do immediately see this chain of logic: $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ implies $f_n\to f$ in measure, so by Riesz' theorem, there exists a subsequence $f_{n_k}\to f$ pointwise a.e. As long as the original sequence converging to $f$ in $L^1$ was continuous, then we are done. But I don't remember that result in my book (Royden and Fitzpatrick). I am used to approximating integrable functions with simple functions but those aren't continuous since they can jump, right? Thanks for the reply though, I will review more.

@geetha290krm oh wait I think I see it. We use Lusin's to get the initial sequence of continuous functions $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$! If so, I'm pretty sure I can work that out and will try now...
